# Caret Package is not loading in Rstudio

Tags: r, r-caret

I had used caret package before in r studio but there was no problem in using caret library. Now iam facing with issue below when i load caret. I have also tried updating R studio and caret package but the issue remains same....ANY HELP GUYS???

```
> library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 cannot open file 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/survival/R/survival.rdb': No such file or directory
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.6.3 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.3
```

Comment: anyone here can help me???

Comment: (re-)install the survival package and see if that helps.